# Set first column as rowname, in spite of duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

```
 sample
      Symobls  IDs Value1 Value2 Value3
 1     NA      NA   3.1    2.3    1.7
 2     TP53   1234  5.8    6.9    10.1
 3     Kras   5678  0.1    0.3    0.5
 4     NA      NA   10.3   2.1    7.9
 5     Hras   9991  20.0   30.0   40.0
 6     TP53   1234  -3.1   0.2    1.7
```

My table looks like this one. 
I need to calculate values by row instead or column. 
So, I tried to Use Symbols as new row names. In this way, I can calculate whole row value by using sample[,"Hras"]
When tried to do this, I encountered this problem.

> rownames(sample)<-sample[,1]
>
> Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
>     duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘A1CF’, ‘A2M’, ‘A2ML1’, ‘AAGAB’, ‘AAK1’, ‘AAMDC’, ‘AARS2’, ‘AASDH’, ‘AASDHPPT’, ‘AASS’, ‘ABAT’, ‘ABCA1’, ‘ABCA13’, ‘ABCA2’, ‘ABCA4’, ‘ABCA5’, ‘ABCA8’, ‘ABCA9’, ‘ABCB1’, ‘ABCB11’, ‘ABCB4’, ‘ABCB5’, ‘ABCB6’, ‘ABCB8’, ‘ABCB9’, ‘ABCC1’, ‘ABCC10’, ‘ABCC11’, ‘ABCC12’, ‘ABCC13’, ‘ABCC3’, ‘ABCC4’, ‘ABCC5’, ‘ABCC6’, ‘ABCC8’, ‘ABCC9’, ‘ABCD3’, ‘ABCD4’, ‘ABCE1’, ‘ABCF2’, ‘ABCG1’, ‘ABHD1’, ‘ABHD10’, ‘ABHD11’, ‘ABHD12’, ‘ABHD13’, ‘ABHD17B’, ‘ABHD2’, ‘ABHD5’, ‘ABHD6’, ‘ABI1’, ‘ABI2’, ‘ABI3BP’, ‘ABL2’, ‘ABLIM1’, ‘ABLIM2’, ‘ABO’, ‘ABR’, ‘ABRA’, ‘ABTB1’, ‘ABTB2’, ‘ACAA1’, ‘ACAA2’, ‘ACACA’, ‘ACACB’, ‘ACAD10’, ‘ACADL’, ‘ACADSB’, ‘ACAN’, ‘ACAP1’, ‘ACAP2’, ‘ACAP3’, ‘ACAT1’, �� [... truncated]

Is this because of the "NA"? Other options?
Thanks

This is a microarray dataset. I have done normalization and going to extract values of several genes to perform plot, cross-correlation and t-test. In fact, not only NA but several genes that I am going to use for plotting figures have multiple rows. So, I need to extract them into another table for later use.

Comment: No, it's because "duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed" as the error message says.

Comment: The error is telling you what happend

Comment: Why do you need to change the data to do this?  There are `rowSums` and `rowMeans` functions.  But you haven't told us what you are calculating

Comment: As Richard said, their should be an easier way to achieve what you want to do. Please, provide more context. (What values are you referring to?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I am just answering a way to change the `row.names` as you requested in the question.  The ultimate goal is not clear.  For the specified problem, you could try using `make.names` with option `unique=TRUE`.  This will make sure that duplicates are named differently.  In the first column, there are `NA` values, which will be named as `NA.`, `NA..1` etc.. (if that is okay for you).

```
 row.names(sample) <- make.names(sample[,1],TRUE)
```

Or as commented by @Richard Scriven,

```
row.names(sample) <- paste(make.unique(df[,1]))
```

Another option would be to convert `data.frame` to `matrix` (which will permit duplicate values).  I would recommend this only if the `columns` are of the same class.  For example, if you have `character` and `numeric` columns, this will convert all the columns to `character` class.  In your dataset, it seems to me that except the first column, all others are numeric (with the possible exception of "IDs" column).  But again the `NA` values would be a problem.  If you want to subset the '1st' or '3rd' row based on the rownames, it will be difficult.

```
sample1 <- as.matrix(sample[,-1])
row.names(sample1) <- sample[,1]
sample1['Hras',]
#  IDs Value1 Value2 Value3 
#  9991     20     30     40
```

Comment: @RichardScriven  I just noticed by testing `row.names(sample) <- make.unique(sample[,1])#
Error in row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*, value = c(NA, "TP53", "Kras",  : 
  missing values in 'row.names' are not allowed`

Comment: I suppose you could trick R and replace the NA values with `paste(NA)` before running `make.unique`, but you didn't hear that from me :-)  `is.na(paste(NA)) # [1] FALSE`

Comment: For me , it is all FALSE, `is.na(paste(make.unique(df[,1])))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`